# Elementar cell of Y2O3

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, crystal-structure

I think this [picture from wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yttria-stabilized_zirconia) is wrong because I count:

\begin{align}
\left.
\begin{array}{ccccr}
1&×&1 &= &\ce{1~Y} \\
6&×&\frac{1}{8} &= &\ce{\frac{3}{4}O}
\end{array}
\right\} \text{ gives }\ce{Y4O3}
\end{align}

How would be the correct elementary cell of $\ce{Y2O3}$?

(I didn't found any correct elementary cell using google)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The picture in Wikipedia doesn't give you the primitive cell. In Yttria, $\ce{Y2O3}$, 8 metal ions are in the special positions $\frac{1}{4}$, $\frac{1}{4}$, $\frac{1}{4}$; the remaining 24 metals occupy the sites $u$, $0$, $\frac{1}{4}$. The 48 oxygen ions are in general positions $x$, $y$, $z$, and are arranged in distorted octahedra around the metal ions, the metal-oxygen bonding distances being unequal. So, the stoichiometry is $\ce{Y32O48}$ which gets simplified to $\ce{Y2O3}$. This structure is generally referred to as the *C*-type metal oxide structure. All the sesquioxides of the rare earths belong to this system, as do $\ce{Ga2O3}$, $\ce{In2O3}$, $\ce{Tl2O3}$ and the mineral bixbyite, $\ce{(Fe, Mn)2O3}$. The primitive cell looks like this (oxygen ions are red, metal ions are gray)

[image]

[Here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tl2O3#mediaviewer/File:Tl2O3structure.jpg) another view which might show more easily that indeed the positions of all the 48 oxygen atoms are different in such a way that no smaller primitive cell can be found.

**Reference**

M. G. Paton, E. N. Maslen, *Acta Cryst.* **1965**, *19*, 307-310